# How to use loop action in Jquery?

Tags: jquery

I am developing a CRUD application using DWR & Jquery. I want to display the table records
from database. I want to put a loop to do that. While searching for that, i ve came across
each() method in Jquery. I cant get its exact concept. Any idea, or solution??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two types of `.each()` method in jQuery.

The first is a method of every jQuery object and iterates over the object, which usually contains an array of DOM elements. An example would be:

```
$('.someClass').each(function(i,val) {
    // "i" references the current index in the iteration
    // "val" references the value (normally DOM element) stored in the jQuery object.
 });
```

- http://api.jquery.com/each/

The other type is more generic. It is meant to iterate over any type of collection. It is equivalent to a javascript `for()` loop.

```
$.each(array, function(i,val) {
    // "i" references the current index in the iteration
    // "val" references the value at that index of the collection.  
});
```

With `$.each()` you could iterate over a javascript object, or other types of collections like a `NodeList` or a jQuery object.

It is what jQuery calls internally when you use the first `.each()` version noted at the top.

- http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

Comment: Thanks, I can move on it now.

Answer (score 1):

The each function allows you to iterate over each element that matches the selector used.  You can see an example in the [jquery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/each/).

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's each() method is used to iterate through the contents of a jQuery object. In your case I think you would just want to use a simple JavaScript 'For Loop' and append() an element containing the record's information each time.